# Are "if (arr.get(i) - arr.get(j) == 0)" and "if (arr.get(i) == arr.get(j))" different?

Tags: java, if-statement

Are these 2 statements different in any way?

```
if (arr.get(i) - arr.get(j) == 0)
if (arr.get(i) == arr.get(j))
```

Because I got different passed test cases.

`if (arr.get(i) == arr.get(j))` passed only 7/10 test cases. Someone changed it to `if (arr.get(i) - arr.get(j)==0)` and all test cases passed.

This was the only difference in the code.

Comment: I am guessing you want `if((arr.get(i) - arr.get(j))==0)` instead of `if(arr.get(i) - arr.get(j)==0)`

Comment: Please don't shout. Lists can't contain primitive values, so comparing the identity may lead to surprising results.

Comment: Why are you [SHOUTING](https://www.netlingo.com/word/shouting.php) at us?

Answer (score 3):

The two statements are not the same. Assuming that `arr` is a collection of a `Number` class (eg `List<Integer>`), this expression:

```
arr.get(i) - arr.get(j)
```

unboxes the object to the corresponding primitive (eg `int`), then performs the arithmetic subtraction, while this expression:

```
arr.get(i) == arr.get(j)
```

Tests if the two object are *the same* object (the same object reference), which is not what you want.

The correct way to test if two objects represent the same *value* is via the `equals()` method.

The best way to fix the code is to use `equals()`, not subtraction:

```
arr.get(i).equals(arr.get(j))
```